# How can I limit Skype Growl notifications to specific users?

Tags: macos, skype, growl

Is there any way to limit Skype Growl notifications to specific users?

I don't care about when everyone in my friend list is going online or offline, especially when that thing happens when they go on and off every like 2 minutes (probably due to network problems).

Using another Skype client is not an option, I like the official one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype registers the following notification types with Growl:

[image]

You cannot distinguish between contacts here, so that's a dead end.

---

Skype only allows global configuration about which events spark a Growl notification in its preferences:

[image]

There is no contact-specific configuration e.g. in a contact's profile. You also cannot open an arbitrary shell script when an event occurs, so that you could call `growlnotify` yourself.

---

In conclusion: It's not possible with the official Skype client.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Contact Alerts for Skype, it's an add-on that lets you create alerts for specific contacts:

http://www.contactalertsforskype.com

Disclosure: This is a commercial app & I know the author

Comment: Looks useful, but looks a bit like a advertisement? Ryan, any disclosure information you might want to add?

Comment: Good call, done

Comment: I don't care if it's an advertisement, it looks awesome, thanks! Just installed it, let's see how it goes.

Comment: Let us know how you get on... I'll be happy to pass on any feedback you've got to the developer too.

Comment: Is there going to be support for platforms other than Mac OS?